# Fopen returns null unless explored there?

Tags: c, null, fopen, explorer

This is a very odd error.

I am using Visual Studio 2012, and in a C++ project (as a container for a C project), I am loading a file in this way:

```
const char* fname = "SomeFile.csv";
if(!(fp = fopen(fname, "r")))
{
    printf("Error! Could not open %s!\n",fname);
    return;
}
```

The CSV is in the same folder as the .EXE, and that is the intention for this program.

1.  When I run it in debug, it fails to read the CSV.

2.  When I put in the full pathname to the file, it works correctly and loads the CSV.

3.  When I go to the output folder in Windows Explorer, and run the .exe, it correctly loads the CSV.

4.  Now here is the weird part.  When I go to another folder (anywhere else), and I then paste in the full path including the .exe into Windows Explorer, it starts up the program, as it should, but it fails to read the CSV.

As a caveat, if I have the folder loaded in explorer, but run it in the VS2012 debugger, it also fails to load the CSV.

What is going on here?  Why would it only find it if I am running it while the window is open in explorer?

Comment: You need to set the working directory on VS to the folder where the file is.

Comment: @Nick In most other languages, a file open command's default location to look is the location of the program it is running in.  Is that not the case in C?

Comment: It depends on IDE. There is no standard about that.

Comment: No, it's not the case in C. It just gives the filename the operating system, and it finds the file. Unless the environment you're using to run the program automatically changes to the directory of the program, it will use whatever your current directory is.

Comment: And I don't think most other languges do what you say, either. PHP doesn't, Perl doesn't, shells don't.

Comment: @Barmar I have not worked with those languages, but I suppose "most" was an assumption.  I guess I was thinking of a couple examples and extrapolating.  In HTML just stating a filename accesses the file of that name in the same directory as that HTML file.  In C#, a fileOpenDialog defaults to the directory you are in (though I do not know about a direct file open command, I have mostly used the dialog there).

Comment: @Nick How do you programmatically (in windows) find the path that your EXE currently resides in?

Comment: `GetCurrentDirectory()` I think (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), to change it on VS for everytime you debug, you have to go to debug settings.

Comment: @Nick I did find that, but was having some trouble implementing it, but I know I was in the right place now.  Thanks.

Comment: `In HTML just stating a filename accesses the file of that name in the same directory as that HTML file` -- HTML is not a programming language or a program that is executing. It is the web browser that sees the bare filename and *figures out* that it should get that file from the same place (web server or filesystem path) the HTML file came from; this is by no means automatic.

Comment: @StephenP I did just say "language" not "programming language" in that statement, and I did not say it was "automatic", but "default", from the code-writer's perspective.  But yes, I did not fully think through that statement.  Nonetheless, a "working directory" as opposed to the directory the file was in, is certainly not as intuitive.  I can see where it comes from, but I have not found a different behavior of an EXE depending on where the explorer window that has focus is opened to.  That much is not something I have experienced before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fopen`, `open`, etc. will, given a bare filename with no path components, attempt to open the named file in the "current directory". Given a filename without a filesystem root it will attempt to open the file in a directory *relative* to the current directory. Only when given an absolute (full) path will it look exactly where you've told it.

In a command-line based system, the current directory is pretty obvious - it's the directory you are in when you issue the command.

In a Graphical User Interface the notion of a current directory is a bit more mushy:

- Navigate in Windows explorer to the program (let's say `WORD.EXE`) and double click it - the current directory is likely to be the directory where the program is - the place to which you navigated (but there's no standard that says this has to be the case)
- Navigate to your documents for your project and double click a Word document, which launches WORD.EXE automatically - what is the current directory? It's likely to be where the document is.
- Launch WORD.EXE from the Start menu - what the heck is the current directory now?
- Launch your program from the debugger - *now* what is the current directory?

This last point is why you have to tell the IDE / debugger what to use as the current directory when it launches your program.

The `fileOpenDialog` doesn't exactly "default" to the current directory - it open to where you last opened it, *without changing the current directory for the program* - when you pick a file it then passes the *full path* of that file to the program.